# C - Printing null character using %c in nested printf statement

Tags: c, null, printf

Why both inner printf() functions are working different even the printing value is same for both functions ? 
Here is the code -:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char ch = '\0';

    printf("%d",printf("%c", ch)) ;
    // This line will print 1.

    printf("%d",printf("\0")) ;
    // This line will print 0.
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code into your question as text.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The only thing worse than posting pictures of code is posting *links* to pictures of code. Pictures cannot be searched by future readers, and links can/and do, rot. Links to code, thus, suffer from *both* afflictions. The code, as properly formatted and indented *text*, belongs in the body of your post.

Comment: With that line: "printf("%c", ch)" you tell explicitely that you want to print one character thus printf returns "1". And, with second line: "printf("\0")" there is nothing to be printed. If you e.g. call printf("\0dsfsdfs") you would also get "0" as return value.

Comment: The literal string `"\0"` is really an array of *two* characters, the `'\0'` you explicitly wrote, and another `'\0'` added by the compiler. Also remember that escape sequences in string and character literals are expanded by the compiler. That means `char ch = '\0';` is essentially translated as `char ch = 0;`.

Comment: Lastly, a [good `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) could be useful to read. Pay attention to [what `printf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  printf("%d", printf("%c", '\0'));
> ```
>
> Why this line prints 1?

The value `'\0'` is one single character, which `"%c"` sends th stdout (though you can't see it).

> ```
>  printf("%d", printf("%s", "\0"));
> ```
>
> Why this line prints 0?

The string `"\0"` has two characters in it: the literal `'\0'` and the implied `'\0'`. None of them are printed with `"%s"`, the first zero terminates the string. The string `"foo"` has 4 characters: the 3 literal ones and the implied `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to man page of printf

```
man 3 printf
```

printf returns the following

```
RETURN VALUE
   Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).
```

So it does not return the count of null bytes.

In the first `printf` you are explicitly telling to print 1 character, so the output is 1. In the second `printf` there is nothing to print or `NULL`. So the output is 0

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char ch = '\0';

    printf("%d",printf("%c", ch)) ;
```

The inner call to `printf()` prints a null character (you don't see it) and returns `1` as the number of characters printed, which is then printed as the string `1` (you get a null plus a digit `1`).

```
    // This line will print 1.

    printf("%d",printf("\0")) ;
```

In this case, you supply a string literal ended in two consecutive null chars, which results on printing an empty string (literally `""`) and that results in passing to the second printf a `0` and the second printf prints it as the string `0`.

```
    // This line will print 0.
   return 0;
}
```

So, you are wrong, in the first case you got a null character printed (a true `\0` befpre tje 1. But a null is ignored by the terminal you are using and it doesn't show in your screen, while the second doesn't print anything·)

## NOTE

Every C language string related function, explores the string to know how long it is, or when to stop the task it is doing.  Putting more than the default string literal's last null char `\0` does nothing but shorten the useful part of the string literal.  If you try to print `"Se está quemando la serrería\0... Duduap!!"` or operate on it with any of the string related functions, you'll get the same result as if you had stopped before the first `\0` character.  So the string literal above is basically equivalent to just `"Se está quemando la serrería"`

Answer (score 0):

They are working different because first inner `printf` is printing a character and that character is a null character which has length of 1. While in your second inner `printf` you are trying to print a string which only contains null character, but due to null character the string became empty with length 0. This is the reason why your first outer `printf` printed 1 and second outer `printf` printed 0.